# My player (keyboard) controls are very sensitive in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following Brackeys tutorial and whenever I press the left button (a) my player falls of the platform because of how sensitive the controls are for some reason. Can somebody help me? I'm using this:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5QFsefuO2RlAgWEz6EvVi6
I'm at Ep 6. Dont know where to put te code.
My player movement code is

```
using UnityEngine;
```

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

```
// This is a reference to the Rigidbody compnenet called "rb"
public Rigidbody rb;

public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

// We marked this as "Fixed"Update because we
// are using it to mess with physiscs.
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Add a forward force.
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); 

    if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your code for moving the character

Comment: I did that -  I added my playerMovement script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower these values

```
public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
```

in the script change to

```
public float forwardForce;
public float sidewaysForce;
```

then you can set it in the inspector and it wont override in script

Comment: By how much do I need to lower?

Comment: And in the inspector I'm able to edit these two values but it doesn't update in the script.

Comment: I edited my answer to help you get around the script, you will have to play with the values and test a few times

Comment: no worries if it solved your problem please mark as correct and upvote

Answer (score 0):

I've found that multiplying the movement with Time.deltaTime, which basically just multiplies it with how much time it's been since the last frame rendered. I googled the tutorial i *think* you're using [(first person movement in unity)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc) and it says at 14:09,
`controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime)`
Hope this helps!